# Greenplum: Not able to drop/truncate tables

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a table in Greenplum(4.3.5.1), i want to remove constraint as initially created with a primary key constraint. I tried to do but query is running for 2-3 hours, i have cancelled it as no other option left,

then i have takne a backup and tried to drop table but query is running 2-3 hours and finally i cancelled the query again
(When drop table query executed, it is showing RowExclusiveLock on table pg_depend, pg_class and pg_type)

I just tried truncate also but same problem

Can anyone help on this, what could be the reason?? and what will be the best way to resolve this??

Regards

Comment: select procpid, substring(current_query, 1,20), now() - query_start from pg_stat_activity order by 3;  Find the procpid blocking your work and then kill it with select pg_cancel_backend(<procpid>);

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you hit a locking issue. First thing to check is `pg_locks` - it would show you the current locks on the table. I bet your table is locked by some process, this is why `truncate` and `drop table` is hanging. Find the blocking query and terminate it, then you would be able to easily drop/truncate target table.

Here is the query that would help you:

```
select * from pg_locks where relation = 'mytablename'::regclass::oid;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I checked the locks, but there is no such rows in pg_locks table

Comment: You might have connected to the wrong database. When you have a hanged query to tableX and you query pg_locks, you would at least see the lock of this hanged query, the output cannot be empty

Comment: When i tries to drop or truncate table, then it is showing in pg_lock, but no other query locks this table, i have only 1 database in my env

Comment: again, truncate would hang if the table is locked or pg_class is locked. Simply find the session ID and check pg_locks for all the locks related to this session ID. Some of them won't be granted, then find the other process who is blocking the object you need

Answer (score 1):

You should use truncate:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  table_name;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html

Comment: Istvan, Thanks for your reply, I wrote in my initial comment also that i tried truncate table but same problem no response till 30-35 minutes